# Create my own mvc structure with node.js, express and use restful api

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, crud

I wanted some MVC structure that was something and objective, without "mimimi".

I found nothing, so I'm creating my own MVC framework with restful api. I'm having some trouble in passing the data of my controllers for the route. Can anyone help me?

I am creating on top of the generator expression, and is a structure that separates server / client. This is the structure until now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tffc1.png

Note the separation client/server.

controllers.js:

```
var example = require('./models/example');

exampleController = function() {

    // POST
    this.create = function(req, res, params) {

    };

    // GET
    this.read = function(req, res, params) {

    };

    // PUT
    this.update = function(req, res, params) {

    };

    // DELETE
    this.delete = function(req, res, params) {

    };

};

module.exports = exampleController;
```

Can i make the renderization for some route here?

This is my client.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var exampleController = require('../controllers/example');



router.get('/', function(req, res) {

});


module.exports = router;
```

How can i use the function on the controller in my routes?

Little lost here..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just loading each controller at startup passing to each controller the router object:

Use this module to load each controller at startup:

```
module.exports = function(router) {
    var fs = require('fs');

    // Setup controllers
    var controllers = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/controllers'); // <-- use your controllers path 

    controllers.forEach(function(controllerName){
        var module = require('./controllers/' + controllerName);

        if (typeof handle === "function") {
            module(router);
        }
    });
};
```

Then `exampleController` may be like this:

```
var proto = exampleController.prototype;

function exampleController(router) {

    // GET
    router.get('/', proto.index)
};

proto.index = function(req, res) { ... };

module.exports = exampleController;
```

Remember to call the first module in your entry point .js file :

```
i.e: server.js:

var controllersLoader = require('path-to-module');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

controllersLoader(router);
```

Comment: i solved with other solution @Daniel, but your solution is great too! Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will simply use the function from you controller as a callback for a router get, post, etc. method:

```
var exampleController = require('../controllers/example');

router.get('/', exampleController.read);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the app.put(), app.post(), app.get() and app.delete() calls that are part of Express. This means you have to change your module's structure to pass the express app into an initialization function to set things up.

```
module.exports = {
    init: function (route, app) {
        app.get(route, function (req, res) {
            // get functionality
        });
        app.put(route, function (req, res) {
            // put functionality
        });
        app.delete(route, function (req, res) {
            // delete functionality
        });
        app.post(route, function (req, res) {
            // post functionality
        });
    }
};
```